# Get precise android device disk space available

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to use adb to find the precise available disk space on an Android device. I'm using this in a powershell command:

```
$deviceInfo = adb shell df
$storageDriveArray = $deviceInfo -match 'data'
$storageDriveString = $storageDriveArray | out-string
$splitStorageDriveString = $storageDriveString -split "\s+"
$freeSpaceString = $splitStorageDriveString[3]


adb shell df
```

works, but doesn't give me enough precision (1.7G will be reported). `df` on Android doesn't seem to take parameters, so I can't use `df -k` or similar to get a more precise value.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

I'm quite new to powershell so please excuse any hacky stuff!

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with PowerShell, it's a question of what interfaces **Android** exposes for retrieving this data. If `adb shell` is the only way to do it (and from what I can tell it is, without installing additional software on the host PC), you have to take what it provides

Comment: Fair point, i'll remove the powershell tag.

Comment: if that's an option you could use `busybox df` instead. it supports more options